# How to get plural translation for string that requires context?

Tags: php, c, gettext

I know that the `gettext` library has [`pgettext()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Contexts.html) which can be used to translate a piece of string for given context. I also know that it has [`ngettext()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html) which can be used to translate string which should have different singular and plurar forms.

How to translate a string which should have different singular and plurar forms *and* depends on context? It seems that logical extension called `pngettext()` doesn't exist.

I'd want to use such behavior from PHP but I'd be happy to know a solution for plain C only.

Comment: There seems to be `npgettext()` in Python's gettext documentation, and for C, a macro by that name is defined in `gettext.h` (but not `libintl.h`).

Comment: Thanks! I think you should write that as a real answer for this question. I looked only at the official documentation (linked in the question) which totally fails to document  `npgettext()`. I also just found a workaround for PHP described here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php#89975

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be `npgettext()` in Python's gettext documentation, and for C, a macro by that name is defined in `gettext.h` (but not `libintl.h`).

Answer (score 1):

Functionality available in [vertilia/text](https://github.com/vertilia/text) userland php library, together with heredoc/nowdoc php syntax which is not parsed correctly by `xgettext` as to my knowledge...

Disclaimer: I am a developer of vertilia/text.